# Extending HTTP Handlers

Tags: go

I have a fairly quick-and-dirty error handler in my Go web app that raises a HTTP error, logs the important parts of the response and serves an error template. I'd like to remove the repetition where I'm writing something like this a few too many times in a handler:

```
err := doSomething()
if err != nil {
    serverError(w, r, err, code)
}
```

I've had a good read of the [Error Handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) article which covers defining a custom HTTP handler type that returns a error type/struct like this (or even returning int, err instead):

```
type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) *appError

type appError struct {
        code int
        Err error
}

// Ensures appHandler satisfies the http.Handler interface
func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := fn(w, r); err != nil {
        switch err.Code {

        case http.StatusNotFound:
            http.NotFound(w, r)

        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            http.Error(w, "message", http.StatusInternalServerError)

        default:
            http.Error(w, "message", err.Code)

        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to retain my existing middleware functionality/wrapper that allows me to chain middleware like this: `r.HandleFunc("/route", use(myHandler, middleware1, middleware2))` where `use` and my middleware look like this:

```
func use(h http.HandlerFunc, middleware ...func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    for _, m := range middleware {
        h = m(h)
    }

    return h
}

 func AntiCSRF(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                // do something
                // h.ServeHTTP(w,r)
            }
     }
```

From what I can figure, it'd be something like the below (which doesn't work). I'm getting an error saying `cannot use m(h) (type http.Handler) as type appHandler in assignment: need type assertion`. How do I resolve this whilst still keeping the middleware itself "as is"?

You can find a (simplified) playground example here: http://play.golang.org/p/Cmmo-wK2Af

```
r.Handle("/route", use(myHandler, middleware.NoCache)) // Contrived example!

func use(h myHandlerType?, middleware ...func(http.Handler) http.Handler) http.Handler {
    for _, m := range middleware {
        h = m(h)
    }

    return h
}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *appError {

    // Extremely contrived example
    name := "Matt"
    _, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi %s", name)
    if err != nil {
        return &appError{500, err}
    }

    return nil
}

func contrivedMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate")
        w.Header().Set("X-Accel-Expires", "0")

        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

What am I missing and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've managed to solve this thanks to the help of 'cronos' on [#go-nuts](https://botbot.me/freenode/go-nuts/msg/10456101/).

The solution allows me to use a custom handler type, chain middleware and avoid the repetition of having to wrap handlers (i.e. appHandler(myHandler)), middleware...):

```
type appHandler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) *appError

type appError struct {
    Code  int
    Error error
}

func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if e := fn(w, r); e != nil {

        switch e.Code {

        case http.StatusNotFound:
            notFound(w, r)
        case http.StatusInternalServerError:
            serverError(w, r, e.Error, e.Code)
        default:
            serverError(w, r, e.Error, e.Code)
        }
    }
}

func use(h appHandler, middleware ...func(http.Handler) http.Handler) http.Handler {
    var res http.Handler = h
    for _, m := range middleware {
        res = m(res)
    }

    return res
}

func someMiddleware(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate")
        w.Header().Set("X-Accel-Expires", "0")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *appError {

    err := doSomething()
    if err != nil {
        return &appError{500, err}
    }

    // render your template, etc.
    return nil
}
```

With routes looking like this: `r.Handle("/route", use(myHandler, someMiddleware))`

You can obviously modify `appHandler` to return whatever you like, add additional fields to `appError` and so on. Your middleware is also able to wrap your router if you want to apply it to all routes - i.e. `http.Handle("/", someMiddleware(r))`